# Evil and org-mode keybinding 't' conflict

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

In Spacemacs with evil and org-mode, the letter 't' is assigned to two functions:

- `org-todo`  (don't need this because I use shift-arrow to cycle through todo states)
- `evil-find-char-to` (I need this)

When in org-mode, 't' only works for `org-todo`.
How to assign 't' to only `evil-find-char-to`?

[This solution by Bernardo Brik worked for Daniel Yang](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs/archives/2016/03/31):

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook ((define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "t") 'evil-find-char-to)))
```

But when I try it:

`add-hook: Invalid function: (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "t") (quote evil-find-char-to))`

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and org-mode on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Hooks are functions, so for the above to work you'd need to wrap your code into an anonymous function instead of an extra set of parens:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "t") 'evil-find-char-to)))
```

I typically use `with-eval-after-load` for this as it avoids creating the function yourself, provided you know what the feature is your code has to be loaded after:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "t") 'evil-find-char-to))
```

Comment: I copy & paste the code in to my dotspacemacs/user-config () and restarted Spacemacs.  But both times code did not changed the 't' behavior; 't' still cycles the heading's todo state.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out what code does it and change the hook/feature accordingly.  I recommend using grep for this on the Spacemacs sources.

Comment: Thanks  wasamasa.  I am going to come back to this after I learn elisp and how emacs works.

Comment: @wolfv did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I have not tried a solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the [readme](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c68fde7bebfbdcee2a44b757f3d887507edf3eba/layers/%2Bemacs/org/README.org) of the Org layer at the current tip of the ‘develop’ branch (r#c68fde7bebfb (“Apply conventions to multi-term keybinds”, 2019-04-05)):

```
If the layer variable =org-want-todo-bindings= is true, the following bindings
are also available.

| Key bindings | Description                         |
|--------------+-------------------------------------|
| ~t~          | Cycle TODO state of current heading |
| ~T~          | Insert new TODO heading             |
| ~M-t~        | Insert new TODO sub-heading         |
```

I infer from this that `t` will *not* be bound to `org-todo` if `org-want-todo-bindings` is set to `nil`.  That is the default according to the `config.el` for that layer.